# Regex search and replace match only

Tags: regex, perl

In perl I have a long string  but here is the important part `$abc = "...Testvalue1   100...";`

Is there a way to use Regex to search for the number right after Testvalue# and replace it with a variable?

Here is what I have so far:

```
my $abc = "...Testvalue1  100...";
for my $i (1..100) {
    $abc =~ s/Testvalue\d+\W+(\d+)/$i/;
    print $abc . "\n";
}
```

Unfortunately this replace the entire match with `$i`, not just the first match of (\d+). Is there a way to do this?

My desired output would be:

```
Testvalue1  1
Testvalue1  2
...
Testvalue1  100
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Perl 5.10 or newer:

```
$abc =~ s/ Testvalue \d+ \s+ \K \d+ /$i/x;
```

(mnemonic for `\K`: "keep" everything to the left)

If you're not:

```
$abc =~ s/ ( Testvalue \d+ \s+ ) \d+ /$1$i/x;
```

(capturing the data you don't want to lose).

Comment: It is a little strange to use `\W+` to match whitespace

Comment: @Borodin admittedly, I didn't think hard about the regex, I just copied and pasted what was in the question and made the needed adjustments for keeping the left part :)

Comment: Now you've broken it! You want `\s+`, not `\W+` or `\w+`

Comment: @borodin argh. Fix it please? I'm away from a computer.

Comment: You can also use postive lookbehind `(?<=TestValue\d+\s+)\d`

Comment: @LLFourn no you can't, because that's a variable-length lookbehind

Comment: Ah yep woops. I tested it on simpler value :)

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you can use:

```
$abc =~ s/Testvalue\d+\W+\K\d+/$i/;
```

`\K` resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ0zN7/1)